# Error when trying to install devise in Ruby on Rails 7.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I'm trying to install devise in the rails version I get the error of the latest version of devise

I have tried with other devise versions but it is update it to the latest,

this is the error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:321:in `ref': undefined method `reference' for ActiveSupport::Dependencies:Module (NoMethodError)
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:340:in `mailer='
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:342:in `<module:Devise>'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise.rb:11:in `<main>'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.0.beta3/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
web_1  |    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
```

if you could help me I'd be grateful

Comment: Rails 7 is still pre-release (current release version is 6.1.4) many gems (especially ones that rely heavily on rails internals like devise) may not work correctly. These issues will likely be resolved by the time rails 7 is actually released, or shortly thereafter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Source of the Error

The version of Devise you're using calls a method named `reference`.
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/c82e4cf47b02002b2fd7ca31d441cf1043fc634c/lib/devise.rb#L320-L323

```
def self.ref(arg)
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.reference(arg)
  Getter.new(arg)
end
```

The method existed in Rails 6:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L651-L653

It has been removed in Rails 7:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb

This line from Rails 7.0.0.alpha1 changelog explains.

> Private internal classes of ActiveSupport::Dependencies have been deleted, like ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Reference, ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Blamable, and others.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md#rails-700alpha1-september-15-2021

#### Fix: Upgrade Devise

Devise has [released a 4.8.1](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#481---2021-12-16) version that's compatible with Rails 7. Run `bundle update devise` to upgrade.

Comment: I found a work around that I just posted but yeah, that would be another alternative in rails 7 that they haven't fixed yet. Thank you very much for your time and answer: D

Answer (score 1):

This fix fixed my bug:

> gem "devise", github: "strobilomyces/devise", branch: "patch-1"

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5397

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Be advised this is a fork of Devise; you won't get any future updates from that library unless strobilomyces keeps that branch up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Devise already merged the fix for this issue with rails 7 to their main branch.

Until a new version is released, you can point the devise gem to use the main branch from GitHub in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/heartcombo/devise', branch: 'main'
```